# iTunes 10 broke Titanium Developer

Tags: itunes, titanium, appcelerator

I installed iTunes 10 just now. When I open Titanium Developer, the SDK version drop-down just says **"loading..."** forever.

Anyone else seen this? Anyone have a fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the Appcelerator team already submitted a patch:

http://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/commit/be36b9d5440ceb3d7c971fb89465697165096724

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling it after 'it got broken' by iTunes?